# Changing integer to long

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I have to change all integer variables to long variables in an application that has a VB6 front end and a jet MDB file backend.

I am planning to do this by

**A. In the program**

1. changing all declarations from 'As Integer' to 'As Long'
   except for built-in paramters such as the 'Cancel as Integer' in the Unload event.
   and
2. Changing all 'CInt' to 'CLng'

And

**B. In the database**

1. deleting the indices
2. adding a temporary integer column with same default value as the column to be replaced
3. copying the data to these
4. deleting the original column
5. creating a new column with the name of the old column
6. copying the data across again
7. deleting the temporary column
8. recreating the indices

Is this a feasible approach? Are there any gotchas?

Comment: dont forget to change your variable names, if the name contains a reference to the type ... like changing intIndex to lngIndex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B. In the table design you can change the data-types/ Number from Integer to Long Integer. You are increasing the size, so this shouldn't be a problem. Copy the tables firstly if you are concerned.

Step A is okay, but you can't change the event argument `Cancel`. Well, you might be able to, but you shouldn't! It won't be necessary/relevant anyway. Don't change such arguments, or any other system (rather than custom) arguments without consideration.

Comment: What @Andrew said is correct. The only thing I would add is if you have a huge number of tables in your DB, you can loop through the tabledefs, and then the fielddefs to find all the integers, and then an "ALTER TABLE" query to change them to long. It could save some time. Also, as far as A. is concerned, watch out for API integer parameters as well.

Comment: @Tom Collins and Andrew Gibson. Thanks I feel a bit more confident going aheaad with this now. I don't think I can use Alter Table, though as the database is Access 97?

Comment: @kjack You can use ALTER TABLE in sql-statements that you create and run from VBA-code (via DAO). However, if you don't have too many tables, it will probably be quicker to change the data-types manually. If you choose the Tools menu (if I recall correctly?), Database Tools, Documentor, you can print out defininitions for all the tables, and cross out "Integer" as you go. Be aware, though, that the generated report can run to many pages. You can export it to Word and perhaps reduce it to a manageable size.